# Lower Bound of Bootstrapped CI Out-of-Range

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am using the boot package in R to bootstrap confidence intervals around an estimate of the median. The data is skewed, but the estimator is not biased, thus I am using the Basic Interval. The data is in units of days, from 0-30.

Below are descriptives for the particular variable:

```
         var   n  mean    sd median trimmed   mad min max range  skew kurtosis   se
Var3     3 100  8.65 11.28    2.0    7.06  2.97   0  30    30  0.90    -0.84 1.13
```

When I run the analysis I get a lower bound estimate below 0.

```
> boot.ci(res100,type="basic",index=3)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 5000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = res100, type = "basic", index = 3)

Intervals : 
Level      Basic         
95%   (-1,  4 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

What does this mean? I didn't think it was possible to get an estimate that was not in the original sample.

Comment: It might help to investigate what `boot.ci` with the `type` argument set to "basic" actually does, by taking a look at `boot:::basic.ci` and `boot:::norm.inter`. You could copy the code and step through it using the debugging tools to investigate what's leading to the behavior

Comment: In fact if it's similar to the basic bootstrap CI described [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/08-bootstrap/lecture-08.pdf) (see p8), then I see no clear reason to think it will always stay inside the range of the observed data.

Comment: @Glen_b - I don't think that's exactly what I am using (although it could be the formula just looks different to me). A description of what I am doing is provided [here](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/enst/562/001/docs/lectures/lecture28.htm). I will look into stepping through the code to see what it does. Mainly I'm interested in finding a way to explain this since it contradicts my understanding of CIs.